# react-d3-graph set starting positions for nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, react-d3, react-d3-graph

Does anyone here use the library react-d3-graph?
https://danielcaldas.github.io/react-d3-graph/docs/index.html 
I'm trying to find a way to give my nodes starting positions, I'm unsure how their positions are set upon render right now. Any idea how to do so ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find it in the documentation, but you can just add an `x` and `y` property to a node to give it an initial position. (Works whether you set the prop `staticGraph` or not.)

The following will place node 'a' above node 'b' every time, instead of placing them randomly.

```js
<Graph
  id="test-graph"
  data={{
    nodes: [
      { id: 'a', x: 0, y: 0 },
      { id: 'b', x: 0, y: 1 },
    ],
    links: [{ source: 'a', target: 'b' }],
  }}
/>
```

It's also possible to have coordinates on only some nodes. Then the ones without coordinates will be placed randomly.